# how to convert ticks to momentjs object

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, momentjs, nodatime

I'm using nodatime and it returns ticks. How can I convert ticks to use and format using momentjs?

```
public JsonResult Foo()
{
  var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now.Ticks;
  return Json(now, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

it returns `long` such as `14598788048897648`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't leak `Ticks` out of your API.  Instead, use the `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet` package to allow NodaTime types like `Instant` to be serialized in ISO8601 standard format.  That format is supported natively in moment.js.

See [the user guide page on serialization](http://nodatime.org/userguide/serialization.html), towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you think you can do a code demo on how to use it? For future reference.

Comment: If it's just this one method, you could also just call `.ToDateTimeUtc()` and let the default serializer do its thing.

Comment: I see. But for instance I use the same code above to convert it to other `DateTimeZoneProvider`. Can I still use the returned value from `ToDateTimeUtc()` to convert to other providers?

Answer (score 5):

Moment.js doesn't have a constructor that directly accepts ticks, however it does have [one that accepts the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the epoch](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/), which might be suitable for this :

```
// Dividing your ticks by 10000 will yield the number of milliseconds
// as there are 10000 ticks in a millisecond
var now = moment(ticks / 10000);
```

[This GitHub discussion in the NodaTime repository](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/371) discusses the use of an extension method to support this behavior as well to return the number of milliseconds from your server-side code :

```
public static long ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(this Instant instant)
{
    return instant.Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerMillisecond;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your answer is fine, its just prefered to use standard formats instead of ticks.

Comment: It looks like the previous chain of comments was deleted. I listened to you on [Hanselminutes talking about both NodaTime and Moment.js](http://hanselminutes.com/485/the-problem-with-datetime-nodatime-with-matt-johnson), so I figured that you know far more about either of these libraries than I do and would know when something would work or not.

Comment: Yeah, I was recalling the `System.DateTime` epoch of 0001, but NodaTime uses 1970 like JS and moment. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_Instant_Ticks.htm), the Instant.Ticks property is:

> The number of ticks since the Unix epoch.

And,

> A tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

A Date object takes the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch in its constructor, and since moment uses the Date constructor underneath the covers, you can just use:

```
var value = moment(ticks/10000);
```